# inverse action of cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Suppose we have two vectorsfield A(x,y,z) and B(x,y,z).If we know B = (0,2,1) can we compute A if:

[image]

?

**EDIT**:

After some searching online I found that there are infinitely many vectors fields A(x,y,z) in order for :[image] to be true.However do all these A vectors have something in common with each other?

Comment: $\nabla\times \vec A$ is notation usually used for vector _fields_, not just vectors. Are you saying $\vec B$ is a constant vector field?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Arthur I have edited.

Comment: @Arthur yes B is a costant vector field.

Comment: [Adding a gradient to $\vec A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Inverse) will give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl operator $\nabla \times$ is not injective so you have indeed infinitely many solutions. However, if one particular solution $A_0$ is given such that :

$$ \nabla \times A_0 = B $$

then any other solution $A$ has to satisfy :

$$ \nabla \times (A - A_0) = 0 $$

by linearity of the curl operator. Considering $A - A_0$ instead of $A$, you just look for solutions of :

$$ \nabla \times A = 0 $$

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is equivalent to the existence of a scalar function $\varphi$ such that $A = \nabla \varphi$ (it may be different if you change the base space). This means that your set of solutions is of the form :

$$ \{ A_0 + \nabla \varphi, \varphi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{C}^1 \} $$

Note that the existence of $A_0$ depends on $B$ : namely, $B$ should satisfy $\nabla \cdot B = 0$. See for instance the Biot-Savart law ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law)).